# By finding paticular line write it at paticulat position in the text document

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following after finding this line `Min:30` in the text document I want to write it after this line `stop mon-fri` in the new text documnet or if it possiable in the same text document and then delete the empty newline.

I appreciate any help.

**Simple:**

```
4
stop mon-fri
dominant 05:02 05:32 06:02 06:32 07:02 07:32 08:02 17:02 17:32 18:02 18:32 19:02 19:32
death Radbruch-Platz 05:05 05:35 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:35 08:05 17:05 17:35 18:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
operator 05:08 05:38 06:09 06:39 07:09 07:39 08:09 17:09 17:39 18:09 18:39 19:09 19:39
Min:30
apologized 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
cooperate 05:16 05:46 06:21 06:51 07:21 07:51 08:21 17:21 17:51 18:21 18:51 19:21 19:51
4
stop mon-fri
government computers 04:32 05:07 05:37 06:03 06:33 07:03 07:26 08:03 18:33 19:03 19:33
WASHINGTON 04:34 05:09 05:39 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:28 08:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
suspected 04:38 05:13 05:43 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:34 08:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
Min:15
Chinese 04:43 05:18 05:48 06:15 06:45 07:15 07:24 07:38 08:15 18:45 19:15 19:45
hackers  04:50 05:25 05:55 06:25 06:55 07:25 07:34 07:48 08:25 18:55 19:25 19:55
```

**Result should looks like this**

```
4
stop mon-fri
Min:30
dominant 05:02 05:32 06:02 06:32 07:02 07:32 08:02 17:02 17:32 18:02 18:32 19:02 19:32
death Radbruch-Platz 05:05 05:35 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:35 08:05 17:05 17:35 18:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
operator 05:08 05:38 06:09 06:39 07:09 07:39 08:09 17:09 17:39 18:09 18:39 19:09 19:39
apologized 05:09 05:39 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:41 08:11 17:11 17:41 18:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
cooperate 05:16 05:46 06:21 06:51 07:21 07:51 08:21 17:21 17:51 18:21 18:51 19:21 19:51
4
stop mon-fri
Min:15
government computers 04:32 05:07 05:37 06:03 06:33 07:03 07:26 08:03 18:33 19:03 19:33
WASHINGTON 04:34 05:09 05:39 06:05 06:35 07:05 07:28 08:05 18:35 19:05 19:35
suspected 04:38 05:13 05:43 06:11 06:41 07:11 07:34 08:11 18:41 19:11 19:41
Chinese 04:43 05:18 05:48 06:15 06:45 07:15 07:24 07:38 08:15 18:45 19:15 19:45
hackers  04:50 05:25 05:55 06:25 06:55 07:25 07:34 07:48 08:25 18:55 19:25 19:55
```

**Code:**

```
private static void refill_time_table(String path, String key) {
    int five = 5;
    File file = new File(path + File.separator + key);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(key);
    sb.deleteCharAt(5);
    String resultString = sb.toString();

    String str = Integer.toString(five);
    String newName = resultString.substring(0, 5) + str
            + resultString.substring(5, resultString.length());
    tempArray.add(newName);
    try (PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path + File.separator
            + newName);

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (!line.startsWith("Min:")) {

                writer.println(line);
                //writer.flush();
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Where are you running into problems?

Comment: I find it helpful to think about how you would do it if they were physical objects. If each line was a strip of paper, how would you go about rearranging them?  The code as you have it will remove all `Min:` lines, but that's not what you want.

Comment: @stvcisco: The problem I dont know how to go back with the scanner to the particular line `stop: mon-fri` when I found it the line `Min:`?

Comment: You can't 'go back' easily. Instead, look for it as you go through the list, and once you find it, stop writing out lines until you find the "Min:". So instead of writing out those next few lines, store them somewhere temporary (a `Vector` or a `StringBuffer`) then when you find the "Min:" line, write it out, then dump out those temporary lines and continue.

Answer (score 2):

Add all lines to a collection, track indexes for those tokens and swap list elements:

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("D:\\temp\\dd.txt"));

        String TokenA = "stop mon-fri", TokenB = "Min";
        int indexA = 0, indexB = 0;

        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String temp = sc.nextLine();
            l.add(temp);

            if (temp.equals(TokenA))
                indexA = l.size();
            else if (temp.contains(TokenB)) {
                indexB = l.size() - 1;

                while (indexB > indexA)
                    Collections.swap(l, indexB, --indexB);
            }
        }

        sc.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**// Add code here - to print ArrayList as is to File**

Comment: I thought it is right but it is not since the lines are being swapped and ordered as in the result simple.

Comment: @TheBook I corrected swap logic sometime after posting solution.`while (indexB > indexA)
                    Collections.swap(l, indexB, --indexB);` Check it now.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using a `Queue` to reorganize the lines. Read line by line into a `Queue`. Stop when you find `stop mon-fri` and search for the next `Min:`. Copy it and then delete it from the original in order to continue feeding lines to the `Queue`.

UPDATE: You should delete only the **first** case of `Min:` in the original text. You should also append the contents of the `Queue` to the new file each time you read a **`stop mon-fri`**.

Comment: can not I dump the Queue each time I read `stop` because the number 4 is not always the same it changes from file to file?

Comment: @TheBook Yes, you can.